# How to call a function in a C server from a client

Tags: c, linux, sockets, client, server

I made an application in C that adds structs to a file and now I want to make it work trough sockets, making the client ask the user to submit the fields of the struct and then the server saves it in the file saving a log file for each action made by the client (add,delete,search,etc). How can I do this? also is it possible to call a function residing in the server from the client?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You seem to be suggesting you want to modify source code at run-time (which can be done) _then_ have those modifications accessible from within the same run-time process which made the source changes (which you cannot).  That would require an intermediate build, and launch of new process.  That would be a conceptual software version of this ***[artist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M._C._Escher)***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create socket listener at server and wait for client connection.
When client sends you something, parse it and make the appropriate action.

for example:

```
/* Create the socket and listen to cennections */
sock = create_socket(port);
if (listen(sock, 1) < 0)
{
    perror("listen");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/* Never end loop for socket listen */
while(1) 
{
    /* Accept socket */
    newsock = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &peer, &len);

    /* dump_sockaddr (peer, len); */
    if (newsock >= 0) 
    {
        /* Null-terminate socket buffer */
        bzero(buf, MAXMSG);

        /* Read from socket */
        ret = read(newsock, buf, sizeof(buf));
        if (ret > 0) 
        {
            printf("Recieved command: %s\n", buf);

            /* Parse command from buffer */
            if (strstr(buf, "deletesomethig") != NULL) 
            {
                /* Make the appropriate action */
                delete_something();
            } 
            else if (strstr(buf, "stopsomething") != NULL) 
            {
                /* Make the appropriate action */
                stop_something();
            }
            else 
                 printf("Recieved unsupported command: %s\n", buf);

            /* Close socket */
            close(newsock);
        }
    }
}

/* Close socket */
close(sock);
```

Just be sure that strstr() has no trouble with memory. This is simple example, you can use sscanf() for parsing commands from socket buffer.